# Remapping the order of -/_ key

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra

I have found lots of answers about remapping one key to another('A' to 'B')but cant seem to find how to swap the order of a single key so that shift+(-/*) gives me a dash(-) and a single press alone give me an underscore (*). I would prefer a command line DIY solution (like Technical Note TN2450 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) than having to download a program.

Comment: It would be a couple minutes work to make a custom layout like this with http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen that you prefer cmd line solution but I would like to suggest you to try **Karabiner**, I'm using it for ages and it is really powerfull.

### Karabiner

> A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for macOS.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/